# Array as a state in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

How can I make sure my array is not empty when trying to print it out like this? ClientCodeRegional is my array and sometimes it could be empty.

```
      {
       this.state.user.ClientCodeRegional[0]?
       <ul>{this.state.user.ClientCodeRegional.map((number) => <li key={number.toString()}>{number}</li>) }</ul>
        :null
      }
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use

```
   {
       this.state.user.ClientCodeRegional.length &&
       <ul>
            {this.state.user.ClientCodeRegional.map((number) => 
                <li key={number.toString()}>{number}</li>) }
        </ul>
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can check for the array length.

```
  {
   this.state.user.ClientCodeRegional.lenght && 
     <ul>{this.state.user.ClientCodeRegional.map((number) => 
        <li key={number.toString()}>{number}</li>) }
     </ul>
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Check the length of the array ClientCodeRegional and if it is > 0 then show your list with the loop on the ClientCodeRegional.

```
 {
   this.state.user.ClientCodeRegional.length>0 && 
     <ul>{this.state.user.ClientCodeRegional.map((number) => 
        <li key={number.toString()}>{number}</li>) }</ul>
 }
```

Comment: Please add further explanation to your answer. Code only answers are not helpful to learners. Use the [edit] button to add more text.

Answer (score 0):

You should use destructuring assignment for shorter code

```
const { ClientCodeRegional } = this.state.user

{
  ClientCodeRegional.length &&
  <ul>
   { ClientCodeRegional.map( number => <li key={number}>{number}</li>) }
  </ul>
}
```

I've just wondered why do you need to convert `number.toString()` for `key`  attribute. I think it converts automatically.